# Conditional variables in JQ json depending on argument value?

Tags: json, environment-variables, jq

I am trying to build a json with jq with --arg arguments however I'd like for the json not to be able to have a condition if the variable is empty.

An example, if I run the following command

```
jq -n --arg myvar "${SOMEVAR}" '{ $myvar}'
```

I'd like the json in that case to be `{}` if myvar happens to be empty (Because the variable ${SOMEVAR} does not exist) and not `{ "myvar": "" }` which is what I get by just running the command above.

Is there any way to achieve this through some sort of condition?

UPDATE:

Some more details about the use case

I want to build a json based on several environment variables but only include the variables that have a value.

Something like

`{"varA": "value", "varB": "value"}`

But only include varA if its value is defined and so on. The issue now is that if value is not defined, the property `varA` will still exist with an empty value and because of the multiple argument/variable nature, using an if/else to build the entire json as suggested will lead to a huge amount of conditions to cover for every possible combination of variables not existing

Comment: A double quote is *not* the same as two single quotes

Comment: Yes I am well aware however I was limited to only using one quote type so I had to write it this way. It works just as well as with double-quotes

Comment: No, it does not. `${SOMEVAR}` is currently unquoted. If it contains a space it would be subject to word splitting

Comment: I have to test that but so far I have not had any issues. Unfortunately I am limited to either one or the other and my tests showed that double quoting the actual json part does not work well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a template of variable names, in the form of an object as you have suggested you want:

```
{a, b, c}
```

Suppose also (for the sake of illustration) that you want to pull in the corresponding values from *ix environment variables.  Then you just need to adjust the template, which can be done using this filter:

```
def adjust: with_entries( env[.key] as $v | select($v != null) | .value = $v );
```

Example:

Assuming the above filter, together with the following line, is in a file named adjust.jq:

```
 {a,b,c} | adjust
```

then:

```
 $ export a=123
 $ jq -n -f -c adjust.jq 
 {"a":"123"}
```

Comment: This was a very good solution. It gave me what I was looking for thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if/else` construct:

```
jq -n --arg myvar "${SOMEVAR}" 'if ($myvar|length > 0) then {$myvar} else {} end'
```

Comment: Thanks you but that would be too complicated if one is using several args. The if/then needs to be per variable inside the json rather than for the whole thing. Is this the only way?

Comment: At least the only way I'm aware of.

Comment: 1.  If you really need to use multiple --arg parameters (which I doubt is the case), you could add a suitable def, e.g. jq -n -c --arg myvar foo 'def z: if length > 0 then {(.): . } else {} end; $myvar|z' 2. Have you thought about alternative approaches that would not require multiple command-line parameters?  It might help to describe the problem you're really trying to solve.

Comment: Actually that is exactly the case. Nothing complicated I just want to build a json based on several environment variables but only include the variables that have a value. Something '{"varA": "value", "varB": "value"}' and only include varA if its value is defined and so on.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not clear where the variable-value pairs are coming from, so maybe it would be simplest to construct the object containing the mapping before invoking jq, and then passing it in using the --argjson or --argfile option?